# How to use large size images for my offline app

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-drawable, android-image

For my app, iam using more than 20 High quality images in drawable to set as background image for screens, Iam using glide  to load the images.. I want know this is correct way to implement high resolution images for my app. every images contains 5 copies in drawable (mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi...).. Is there any other way to overcome size issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `VectorDrawable` which seems to fit your needs. You can read more about it in the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources).

Comment: for icons using svg is correct, but iam using images as background to my screens

Comment: @NavinKumar Seems the correct way to do it then. I heard Glide is generally faster than Picasso.

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading your app to the play store, make sure you are using Android App Bundles: https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle

> Google Play's Dynamic Delivery uses your Android App Bundle to build and serve APKs that are optimized for each device configuration. This means your users enjoy a smaller app download without the unused code and resources needed for other devices.

Comment: using bundle will reduce the size of APP as compared to APK.. but my question is how to manage large no of images files in drawable.. for offline app

Answer (score 0):

**You have copy your large image on asset folder and use image from asset folder**

```
try 
{
    InputStream ims = getAssets().open("large_image.jpg");
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
    // set image to ImageView
    mImage.setImageDrawable(d);
    ims .close();

} catch(IOException ex) {}
```